# Comparing doubles in Java gives odd results

Tags: java, double, equals, autoboxing

I really can'get my head around why the following happens:

```
Double d = 0.0;
System.out.println(d == 0); // is true
System.out.println(d.equals(0)); // is false ?!
```

This however works as expected:

```
Double d = 0.0;
System.out.println(d == 0.0); // true
System.out.println(d.equals(0.0)); // true
```

I'm positive that this is related to autoboxing in some way, but I really don't know **why `0` would be boxed differently when the `==` operator is used and when `.equals` is called**.

Doesn't this implicitly violate the `equals` contract ?

```
  *  It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value
  *     x, x.equals(x) should return
  *     true.
```

**EDIT**:

Thanks for the fast answers. I figured that it is boxed differently, the real question is: **why** is it boxed differently ? I mean that this would be more intuitive if `d == 0d` than `d.equals(0d)` is intuitive and expected, however if `d == 0` which looks like an `Integer` is `true` than 'intuitively' `d.equals(0)` should also be true.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

just change it to

```
System.out.println(d.equals(0d)); // is false ?! now true
```

You were comparing double with `Integer` 0

### **Under the cover**

```
System.out.println(d.equals(0)); // is false ?!
```

`0` will be autoboxed to `Integer` and an instance of Integer will be passed to `equals()` method of `Double` class, where it will compare like

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return (object == this)
                || (object instanceof Double)
                && (doubleToLongBits(this.value) == doubleToLongBits(((Double) object).value));
    }
```

which is going to return **false** of course.

### **Update**

when you do comparison using `==` it compares values so there is no need to autobox , it directly operates on value. Where `equals()` accepts `Object` so if you try to invoke `d1.equals(0)` , `0` is not Object so it will perform autoboxing and it will pack it to Integer which is an Object.

Comment: Or just settle for `d == 0`? :)

Comment: @Simeon answered your question from comment

Comment: How can it compare values when `d` is an object and 0 is primitive ? IMO it either unboxes `d` (to `int` ? or maybe uses `Double.doubleValue()` ?) or boxes 0, I don't see how it can perform `==` on an object and a primitive otherwise. Perhaps I should ask a separate question about this since this one is getting a bit tangled ...

Comment: it will invoke `d.doubleValue() == 0` , please read more about it in [JLS 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html)

Comment: So, we could say for `d == 0` it is not autoboxed, but autounboxed.

Comment: @Paulo yep :) it doesn't 'touch' the primitive int, rather it calls `d.doubleValue()` on the `Double` object. Now I'm wandering if this is JVM implementations specific, but this is another topic :D

Comment: @Simeon: this is not JVM specific, since it is specified by the JLS.
Jigar Joshi, sorry for the previous comment, I was confused; you're talking about the unboxing conversion, but then you should mention
the (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)[JLS 5.1.8].

Answer (score 6):

`Number` objects only equal to numbers with the same value if they are of the same type. That is:

```
new Double(0).equals(new Integer(0));
new BigInteger("0").equals(new BigDecimal("0"));
```

and similar combinations are all false.

In your case, the literal `0` is boxed into an `Integer` object.

Comment: Why would it box it to Integer when .equals is called and to something else when == is called ?

Comment: @Simeon because `equals()` accept `Object` , check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230642/comparing-doubles-in-java-gives-odd-results/5230680#5230680)

Comment: @Jigar I did read your answer (I even upvoted), but what boggles me is that when we do the `==` comparison 0 is boxed to `Double` (or is it ?! what is even happening on the == comparison, there should be an object created so it can compare the references correct ?) and when we do `.equals` its boxed to `Integer`

Answer (score 5):

It's probably worth noting that you should compare floating point numbers like this:

```
|x - y| < ε, ε very small
```

Comment: If right value is not 0.0, such as 0.2323121212,I think your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

`d.equals(0)` : `0` is an `int`. The `Double.equals()` code will return true only for `Double` objects.

Comment: `0` is an `int` **and** will be auto-boxed to an `Integer`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer That is all assumed :)

Comment: but apparently not understood by the OP.  It is a good idea to spell these things out.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform

```
d == 0
```

this is upcast to

```
d == 0.0
```

however there are no upcasting rules for autoboxing and even if there were equals(Object) gives no hits that you want a Double instead of an Integer.

Comment: So it actually is not boxed at all on == its just cast, this is the answer I was looking for.