# TreeMap odd natural ordering

Tags: java, collections, intellij-idea, treemap

I have TreeMap which responds to < document_id, document_relevance_factor >. It's an 1:n relation. Then I want to sort resuls by value so I just reverse the map using Map< Double, Set < Integer > >. However, I'm getting some strange results. Output below is from Intellij Idea's debugger, but it's also output generated when not using debugger.

Original map:

[image: Original Map]

.. and another 150 entries. Reversed map below (most of that 150 entries have 0.0 relevance):

Map sorted according to relevance:

[image: Map sorted according to relevance]

My question is, if doubles are ordered according to their natural ordering, how it's possible to have this output?  I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230642/comparing-doubles-in-java-gives-odd-results) stackoverflow post and also tried to provide my own copmarator:

```
Map<Double, Set<Integer>> reverseDocMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Double>() { // default comparator gives odd results
    public int compare(Double d1, Double d2) {

        return (int) ((d1 - d2) * 1_000_000);
    }
});
```

but this does not solve the problem, so I'm nearly 100% sure I'm missing something important but I just can't figure out what is it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm definitely blind, numbers are in scientific notation.

Comment: this can't be an answer. it is a comment.